# JAX-WS: Eclipse Web Service wizard generates wrong stubs

Tags: eclipse, jax-ws, stub

I have a SOAP web service with JAX-WS. There I got a method `createTransaction(String, String, String, int, String[][])`.

When I create a new Web Service client with Eclipse, it however generates stubs with the method `createTransaction(String, int)` which is how the service used to be defined in an older revision. When looking into the WSDL the create method should actually expect 5 parameters instead of 2:

```
<message name="createTransaction"> <part name="arg0" type="xsd:string"/> 
  <part name="arg1" type="xsd:string"/> 
  <part name="arg2" type="xsd:string"/>
  <part name="arg3" type="xsd:int"/>
  <part name="arg4" type="ns1:stringArrayArray" xmlns:ns1="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/array"/>
</message>
```

So, how comes Eclipse generates a stub with only 2 parameters?

Comment: Are you clean the cache? Proxy cache?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something in your workspace has not been updated for your new method signature. You can try doing a clean build of the project, deleting any generated WSDL or XSD files and rebuilding the client. Closing and reopening the project(s) has also helped me previously.

I doubt there is such a blatant defect in the Eclipse tooling so I'd suggest trying to make sure nothing is saved with the old method signature.

As a last resort you could create a new project and move over only your own files (nothing generated by Eclipse) and try again.